# "aptitude -f install" fails

Tags: debian, installation, aptitude, debian-lenny

using debian lenny and trying to do a "aptitude -f install"

I get this error message:

```
Can't exec "locale": No such file or directory at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Encod           ing.pm line 16.
Use of uninitialized value $Debconf::Encoding::charmap in scalar chomp at /usr/s           hare/perl5/Debconf/Encoding.pm line 17.
dpkg: `ldconfig' not found on PATH.
dpkg: 1 expected program(s) not found on PATH.
NB: root's PATH should usually contain /usr/local/sbin, /usr/sbin and /sbin.
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
A package failed to install.  Trying to recover:
dpkg: `ldconfig' not found on PATH.
```

**UPDATE**
I managed to get a bit further. New error message is

```
Can't exec "locale": No such file or directory at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Encoding.pm line 16.
Use of uninitialized value $Debconf::Encoding::charmap in scalar chomp at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Encoding.pm line 17.
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Reading extended state information
Initializing package states... Done
Reading task descriptions... Done
```

So at least ldconfig is back.

** UPDATE 2 **

newest error message:

```
unknown initscript, /etc/init.d/glibc.sh not found.
```

getting there... one step after the other
Does anyone of you have any idea as to why and how to repair this?

Comment: this website has helped me a bit along the road:

http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/debian-26/libc6-upgrade-resulting-in-ldconfig-not-found-on-path-794015/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you did that as root AND you have /sbin, /usr/sbin and /usr/local/sbin in root's path,
you may need to do

```
  apt-get --reinstall install libc6
```

to refresh your libc package from scratch and reinstall some corrupted or  missing binaries.

The locale seetings are a bit trickier; make sure you've got the 'locales' package installed and maybe the 'locales-all' package as well. You might also try (as root):

> `dpkg-reconfigure libc6`

Comment: doesn't work for me. Error message: Package libc-bin is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
E: Package libc-bin has no installation candidate

Comment: got it solved with a bit of copying files from unpacked libc6 / locales downloads!